# Eficiencia de expresiones Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, eficiencia

Estoy tratando de aprender a manejar correctamente las expresiones Lambda en Java y saber cuándo conviene utilizaras y cuándo no.

Para ello, tengo la sencilla tarea de buscar en un arreglo de objetos de tipo `Persona` si hay alguien con algún nombre en particular.

Una solución bastante directa y sencilla (sin implementar expresiones Lambda) podría ser la siguiente:

```
public boolean contieneNombre(ArrayList<Persona> personas, String nombre) {
    for(Persona persona : personas)
        if (persona.getNombre().equals(nombre))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Tratando de implementar una solución con expresiones Lambda, lo siguiente parece funcionar correctamente:

```
public boolean contieneNombre(ArrayList<Persona> personas, String nombre) {
    if (personas.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(nombre))
                .count() != 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es más conveniente hacerlo de la manera *"tradicional"* con un bucle `for` o `for-each`, o el costo computacional de utilizar expresiones Lambda en métodos como `forEach()` o `filter()` es menor? Sé que si me guío por legibilidad, quizás hacer uso de un bucle `for` sea más rápido de comprender; pero, nuevamente, no soy ducho en este tema aún.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que la solución a tu pregunta pasa por escribir código equivalente, con y sin lambdas iterarlo muchas veces y comparar sus tiempos de ejecución. En general pensamos en tiempo para medir rendimiento. En cuanto a divulgadores: en wikipedia: "En algunos lenguajes de programación, las expresiones lambda normalmente son implementadas con propósitos específicos como la vinculación de eventos a devoluciones de llamada, o instanciar la función para valores particulares, lo que **puede ser más eficiente, más legible, y menos propenso a errores** que llamar a una función de nombre más genérico."

Comment: Pero, **eso debe ser leído con pinzas y requiere contrastación** no indican pruebas de la afirmación.

Comment: [Esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675319/which-would-be-better-in-terms-of-performance-lambda-or-simple-loop) de la comunidad en inglés contesta a lo que pides.

Answer (score 2):

He visto tu pregunta y me ha picado la curiosidad, entonces desarrollé un ejemplo rápido para evaluar cual seria la mejor opción. He intentado recrear tu pregunta inicial y me he montado unas pruebas con un arreglo de 20 entradas, la única salvedad es que optimice un pelin tu método de búsqueda con la expresión **lamda**. Prueba tu también y valoramos los resultados. Aunque no es una buena practica monte todo en un solo archivo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}


public class Main {

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> data = buildData();
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           System.out.println("-------------------");
           System.out.println("Iteration " + (i + 1));
           System.out.println("-------------------");

           // select a random number for concat with name to search
           int randomNumber = (int)(Math. random()*20+1);

           System.out.println("Searching: name"+randomNumber);

           // Run find method with bucle
           long startTimeHS = System.currentTimeMillis();
           if (findName(data, "name" + randomNumber)) {
               System.out.print("Find with bucle in ");
           } else {
               System.out.print("Not found with bucle in ");
           }
           System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeHS + "ms");

           // Run find method with lamda
           long startTimeHSLamda = System.currentTimeMillis();
           if (findNameWithLambda(data, "name" + randomNumber)) {
               System.out.print("Find with lamda in ");
           } else {
               System.out.print("Not found with lamda in ");
           }
           System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeHSLamda + "ms");
       }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Person> buildData() {
        ArrayList<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Person("name1", 24));
        data.add(new Person("name2", 15));
        data.add(new Person("name3", 10));
        data.add(new Person("name4", 80));
        data.add(new Person("name5", 44));
        data.add(new Person("name6", 34));
        data.add(new Person("name7", 76));
        data.add(new Person("name8", 22));
        data.add(new Person("name9", 33));
        data.add(new Person("name10", 23));
        data.add(new Person("name11", 76));
        data.add(new Person("name12", 22));
        data.add(new Person("name13", 55));
        data.add(new Person("name14", 56));
        data.add(new Person("name15", 98));
        data.add(new Person("name16", 65));
        data.add(new Person("name17", 43));
        data.add(new Person("name18", 11));
        data.add(new Person("name19", 21));
        data.add(new Person("name20", 44));
        return data;
    }

    public static boolean findName(ArrayList<Person> people, String name) {
        for (Person person : people)
            if (person.getName().equals(name))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean findNameWithLambda(ArrayList<Person> people, String name) {
        return people.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getName().equals(name));
    }
}
```

### Resultados para 5 iteraciones:

[image: Resultados de 5 iteraciones]

Comment: Interesante, tenía la idea de implementar algo similar pero pensé que ya estaba comparada la eficiencia de un método vs el otro en algún lugar de internet que no estaba encontrando. Muchas gracias por el ejemplo, es muy útil. Sin duda voy a replicarlo para ver qué resultados obtengo con más iteraciones.